# VB net 2012 code to search for programs and files as in the windows 7 start menu

Tags: vb.net, search, startmenu

I want to make a textbox similar in function to the search textbox in the windows 7 start menu.
When I search for something in the windows 7 start menu, the process searchindexer.exe runs.
So you would think that is what I have to run in my program. But when I run it, nothing happens.

Someone said to use the Windows API Code Pack for .NET Framework as that provides API hooks for using
the existing Windows Search inside my own applications. Sounds like that is what I want. Can someone get me started on how one uses API hooks, as I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no master of hooks but here

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319524

And here

http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/keyboard/article.php/c4831/Managing-LowLevel-Keyboard-Hooks-with-the-Windows-API-for-VB-NET.htm

Seem to be a good start.

Comment: thanks. what a start. very complicated for me. hope i get a simpler answer or i may pay microsoft for the answer. suchs.